# Checksum utility that integrates into Windows Explorer properties as a tab

Tags: windows, gratis, security, file-format

I once had a utility that integrated into Windows Explorer's file properties dialog as a tab and displayed some typical checksums, like MD5, SHA1 etc.

Googling for it now, I just find [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/), which is very similar but is commercial. IMHO my version of it was fully free, also for commercial use.

Related:

- [This SR question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/167/file-integrity-checker) is for Linux.
- [This SR question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21492/tool-to-validate-the-integrity-of-my-data-files) does not integrate in Windows Explorer
- [This SR question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13714/portable-app-for-calculating-one-selectable-hash-for-a-selected-file) has no answer (upvoted and wondering why it has no answer - such a tool should exist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/)

- integrates into Windows Explorer with a "Checksums" tab
- supports CRC32, MD4, MD5 and SHA-1 checksums
- is open source, licensed under BSD license

It does not calculate the checksum until the tab becomes active. For large files, it shows a progress bar while calculating the checksum(s). Checksums can be saved to files if you want to provide files for download yourself.

The screenshot shows the calculated checksum of a [Kali Linux image](https://www.kali.org/downloads/). The SHA1 checksum is equal to the one listed on the website, so the tool seems to work well.

[image: HashCheck screenshot]